# Retrieving and posting static dropdown data into mysql database in Zend 2

Tags: mysql, drop-down-menu, zend-framework2

I have several fields in my form that i wish to post to the database. All the other fields **bar** the dropdown field are all working fine

The official documentation for zend 2 is not really clear on how to deal with posting data from a dropdown menu into the database

Here's what i have:

my **addAction** in the controller

```
public function addAction()
    {
        $form = new UsersForm();
        $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) 
        {
            $users = new Users();
            $form->setInputFilter($users->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid()) 
            {
                $users->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                $this->getUsersTable()->saveUser($users);

                // Redirect to list of albums
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('index');
            }
        }
        return array('form' => $form);

    }
```

my form

```
public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        // we want to ignore the name passed
        parent::__construct('users');

        //other form elements...

        //the dropdown menu
$this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Select',
            'name' => 'groupid',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Group',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '0' => 'Not Selected',
                    '1' => 'Super Admin',
                    '2' => 'Company Admin',
                ),
            ),

        ));  
        //...
        }
}
```

the view

```
<?php
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('user', array('action' => 'add')));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formRow($form->get('groupid'));
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

When i run my application for the addAction, i get an error message:
**Statement could not be executed (23000 - 1048 - Column 'GroupID' cannot be null)**

where **'GroupID'** is the column in my table that takes the value from the dropdown which means the field is not being posted

I need help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column in your database is `GroupID`, the form element should also be named that. Yours is `groupid` (i.e. lowercase). If that doesn't fix the issue, please edit your question to include the DB structure and the code for the `saveUser()` function.

Comment: You're right..changing the attribute name to 'GroupID' on the form solved it..thanks